# C# TimeZoneInfo to convert GMT timezone name to system timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In windows, we get timezone list like this:

```
ID    Time zone name               Display string
--    --------------               --------------
0     Dateline Standard Time       (UTC-12:00) International Date Line West
110   UTC-11                       (UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time -11
200   Hawaiian Standard Time       (UTC-10:00) Hawaii
300   Alaskan Standard Time        (UTC-09:00) Alaska
```

more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx).

I use this list to convert from one timezone to another using `TimeZoneInfo` class which accepts time zone name shown in above list.

Ex.

```
// Local time zone to UTC
var utcOffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeSpan.Zero);
var localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneName); // here tz name can be any name from above table
var localOffset = new DateTimeOffset(date.Value, localTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(utcOffset));
DateTime utcDate = localOffset.UtcDateTime;
```

Now I came across SalesForce timezone representation like:

```
Time Zone Code  Time Zone Name
--------------  --------------
GMT+14:00       Line Is. Time (Pacific/Kiritimati)
GMT+13:00       Phoenix Is.Time (Pacific/Enderbury)
GMT+13:00       Tonga Time (Pacific/Tongatapu)
GMT+12:45       Chatham Standard Time (Pacific/Chatham)
```

more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_timezone.htm&type=0).

I couldn't find built in functionality to use either `time zone code` or `time zone name` given in above table for the conversion.

Comment: The part in brackets in the SalesForce "time zone name" is the IANA time zone ID. Do you *have* to work with TimeZoneInfo? My [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project integrates well with the IANA time zone information - but if you have other uses of the Windows time zone name, that may not be as good an option as just converting.

Comment: If you just want to convert the IANA ID to a Windows ID, you might want to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/ But be aware that there isn't always a direct correspondence, and the data can be different.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks. I don't have any specific use for Windows tz name. I just need to save the UTC equivalent dates in database. One of the external system sends the info with Windows tz name which I have to convert to UTC and save it to database. Other external system sends tz name in IANA tz ID. I need to convert it to UTC and save it to db as well.  Hence I was looking for common functionality which accepts both the tz names. Thank you for the link. So with Noda, I can deal with both the name formats?

Comment: @JonSkeet So `TimeZoneConverter` does exactly what I need. I can convert IANA tz to Windows tz. Will check on your additional comment regarding direct correspondence. Could you please put the comment as answer so that I could accept? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Noda Time supports BCL names as well, when on the full framework. (Adding an answer about `TimeZoneConverter` now.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're happy to stick with `TimeZoneInfo` and `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset`, you can use Matt Johnson's [`TimeZoneConverter`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/) library to convert the IANA ID (the part in brackets, e.g. Pacific/Kiritimati) to a Windows system time zone ID.

Examples from the [project page docs](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter):

```
string tz = TZConvert.IanaToWindows("America/New_York");
// Result:  "Eastern Standard Time"
```

Or:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/New_York");
```

However, things to be aware of:

- There won't always be a complete mapping from IANA IDs to Windows IDs. Some aren't mapped, although the situation is better than it used to be.
- The Windows time zone data can be different to the IANA data sometimes. (Again, this is getting better.)
- Time zone data changes over time. If you're storing *future* date/time values, you might want to store the time zone and local time rather than the UTC instant. (That instant may not map to the same local time in the future.)
- Some local times can be ambiguous - e.g. if the clocks go back from 2am to 1am on a particular date in a particular time zone, then 1:15am on that day will occur twice in that time zone. Think about how you want to handle that, and test it.

I'd personally recommend using my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library anyway, as a cleaner way of handling date/time, but I acknowledge that if you've got a lot of code dealing with `DateTime` already, that may not be feasible.